# What is probability that an arbitrarily selected person is either female or has chosen $B$

Tags: probability, statistics

Given is

Female total 2500, male total 2000 =total 4500
Party B: female 150, male 700

What is probability that an arbitrarily selected person is either female or has chosen B! I thought of doing 2500+700/4500 but this is not correct. Where am I making a mistake?

Answer: 67.8 %

Comment: To be clear, when you use the phrase "*either ___ or*"  do you include or do you not include "*both*"?  Is that an *inclusive or* or is that an *exclusive or*?  That is to say, are you being asked for $\Pr(X\cup Y)$?  Or are you being asked for $\Pr(X\Delta Y)$?

Comment: "*But this is not correct*"  Why do you say this?  Do you know what the answer was supposed to be?  If you share with us that answer we will better be able to guess as to what the intent of the problem writer was.

Comment: Done @JMoravitz

Comment: Having see the desired answer, it needs an *exclusive or* to be correct , and wanted you not the count the $150$ Party B females at all in the numerator.

Comment: The takeaway that you should have here is that some authors write "*either ___ or*" to mean the *exclusive or*.  It should be emphasized that other authors might use that phrase for the *inclusive or* as well and so the question was ambiguous.  A well-phrased question would have made it perfectly clear which of these meanings was intended.  If you encounter such ambiguity again in the future, if you can ask the question author or a teacher/proctor/TA for clarification, do so.  Otherwise, just be sure that you know how to answer the question for both interpretations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following diagram illustrates the process (F means female, B means 'attends B'):
[image: Venn diagram]
From the diagram one can see that $P = $ (Probability of drawing a female that doesn't attend B) + (Probability of drawing a male that does attend B) $= \frac{2500 - 150}{4500} + \frac{700}{4500} \approx 67.8 \%$.

Note that this is equivalent to $P = P(F) + P(B) - 2P(F \cap B)$ or simply $P = P(F \cup B) - P(F \cap B)$ - refer to the diagram for intuition.